# Number of digits code

Tags: java

I have a problem asking me to tell the amount of digits in a given number. I inserted conditional statements, but no matter what number I insert, it gives me "nine" digits. The code is below. I'm a math student and not computer science, so I figure I'm not using the most efficient method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class E52 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // part 1: import scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // part 2: ask user for a number
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();

        // part 3: tell how many digits are in each number by using string and conditional statements
        String number1Str;
        if (number >= 0 || number <= 10) number1Str = "one";
        if (number >= 10 || number <= 100) number1Str = "two";
        if (number >= 100 || number <= 1000) number1Str= "three";
        if (number >= 1000 || number <= 10000) number1Str = "four";
        if (number >= 10000 || number <= 100000) number1Str = "five";
        if (number >= 100000 || number <= 1000000) number1Str = "six";
        if (number >= 1000000 || number <= 10000000) number1Str = "seven";
        if (number >= 10000000 || number <= 100000000) number1Str = "eight";
        if (number >= 100000000 || number <= 1000000000) number1Str = "nine";
        else number1Str = "undefined";

        System.out.println("There are " + number1Str + " digits in the given number.");

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Logic error. Your `||` should be `&&`. Because you want a logical and, not a logical or.

Comment: It would also be a lot simpler if you used `else if` - then you'd only need a single condition in each test.

Comment: this seems seriously complicated in order to do what you need, but I'm not a java dev. Can you not cast it as a string and determine the length?

Comment: @RobertWade converting it to `String` and using the `length()` method would sure do the trick but I'd assume this is some kind of exercise or homework given.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I did that but now it is giving me "undefined" digits.

Comment: @ElijahDover Use && instead of ||. Also use else if instead of separate if.

Comment: @JonSkeet How would you do else if? My professor doesn't explain these things but hands out homework on it anyways.

Comment: `if (number < 0) { return "negative"; } else if (number < 10) { return "one";} else if (number < 100) { return "two"; } etc`

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to create an Array, then get the input's length and pick let it pick the entry:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

// part 2: ask user for a number
System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
Integer number = sc.nextInt();
final String[] numNames = {
            "",
            "one",
            "two",
            "three",
            "four",
            "five",
            "six",
            "seven",
            "eight",
            "nine",
            "ten",
            "eleven",
            "twelve",
            "thirteen",
            "fourteen",
            "fifteen",
            "sixteen",
            "seventeen",
            "eighteen",
            "nineteen"
    };
System.out.println(numNames[number.toString().length()]);
```

Comment: Well, there are zillions of ways to do that. Very much depends on what his homework expects him to do. In case he has to use if/else ... your solution is pointless.

Comment: Again - I didnt downvote, simply comment.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you number count no matter how big or small number is. Although there are corner scenarios which may fail the code but i still feel this will be of use to you in some other way around

```
public class CountNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String numAsString = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(numAsString.length());
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: And when his assignment asks for using if/else .. your answer doesnt help him.

Comment: Agree.. If the whole point is for teaching if-else and operators, it would not  make sense to proceed in this way. :)

Comment: @GhostCat where does he say the assignment required if/else?  He even admitted he's probably using an inefficient method which implies it was of his own choosing.  He simply stated he needed to find the number of digits.

Comment: Note: I didn't downvote. I am just talking out of experience. When newbies focus on a certain pattern - then often because they are asked to do so.